# Sending a JSON array from one machine to another using PHP cURL - How to construct destination URL from destination IP address

Tags: php, json, curl, networking, wireshark

I have two vitual machines installed in a VMWare Workstation and they both have different IP address. I want to send a JSON array from one virtual machine to the other.  So I am using the PHP cURL library to send the data, and have followed [this tutorial](http://thisinterestsme.com/sending-json-via-post-php/). Below is my code snippet. For the sake of this question, let's suppose that `AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD` is the IP address of the destination host where I want to send the JSON data.

I have two questions:

1. All I know is the IP address of the destination host. That destination computer does have an XAMPP local server on it. NOW how do I contruct that URL for the destination? Please see the first line in the snippet below, am I making up the URL correctly?

2.When I execute this script on the localhost and meanwhile run Wireshark, three packets appear to be sent to the particular destination IP address. BUT I don't know how to receive the particular JSON data in the destination machine? It will be great if someone can point me to a tutorial for that or give me a hint?

```
<?php
$url = "http://AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD"; // AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD is replaced by the IP address of destination host.
    //Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url);

//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array(
    'name' => 'Jeremy',
);

//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);

//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 

//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My simple test example:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost/curl-req.php';
$data = array("name" => "Heniek", "age" => "125", "rozmiar" => "M");   
$data = json_encode($data);                                                                                   
// Send post data Json format
echo CurlSendPostJson($url,$data);
// send curl post                                        
function CurlSendPostJson($url='http://localhost/curl-req.php',$datajson){   
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datajson);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($datajson)));
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, true); //if you want headers
    return $result = curl_exec($ch);
}
?>

<?php
// save belove to: curl-req.php
// GET JSON CONTENT FROM CURL
$jsonStr = file_get_contents("php://input"); //read the HTTP body.
//echo $json = json_decode($jsonStr);
if (!empty($jsonStr)) {
    echo $jsonStr;
}
// POST DATA FROM CURL
if (empty($jsonStr)) {
    echo serialize($_POST);
}
// GET DATA FROM CURL
if (!empty($_GET)) {
    echo serialize($_GET);
}
?>
```

Comment: `http://localhost/curl-req.php` is a destination in your own local server. I need to send JSON data between two different machines.

Comment: It is simple question you need only copy change url and thats it. Longer you write message to me than change url.